# python3: how to enable strong typing?

Tags: python-3.x, strong-typing

Is there a way to get real strong typing in python3, such that one gets a runtime error, when the wrong type is used?
See following example:

```
def pick(k:int = None):
    if k: print("value: ", k)
    else: print("no value")

pick()
pick(1000)
pick("error")
```

this gives the following output:

```
no value       <- can be accepted, and for this example it would be useful
value:  1000
value:  error  <- here should come a runtime error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this, hope will help. This is one of the way to force type checking.

```
def pick(k:int = None):
     assert isinstance(k, int), 'Value Must be of Interger Type'
     print("value: ", k) if k else print("no value")  # Single Line Statement
```

In case of `None` or `string` it will raise `AssertionError`

> AssertionError: Value Must be of Interger Type

However if you really need `ValueError` to be raise then

```
 def pick(k:int = None):
     if not isinstance(k, int):
         raise ValueError('Value Must be of Interger Type')

     print("value: ", k)  if k else print("no value") # Single line statement
```

Exception

> ValueError: Value Must be of Interger Type